# why dosent the image and text on my website show up?

Tags: html

my website has some text, a video and then an image and more text... but the image and text after the video dosen't show up on the website when i open it in the web browser.

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>bruh</title>
            <link rel="icon" href="media/images/happydrip.ico">
    </head>
    
    <body style="background-color:black;">
            <script>
                function imageappear() {
                document.getElementById("image").visible;
                }
                
                
                </script>
                <h1 style="color:white;">my guy</h1>
            <p onclick="gayappear()" style="color:white;">u got drip</p>
            <video width="1300" height="400" src="media/videos/banana.mp4" autoplay />
            
            
            
            <img src="media/images/firstimage.png" id="image" hidden alt="image not found" />
            <p>test</p>
    </body>
```

Comment: The last image has hidden attribute. Remove it then you can see the image.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `imageappear` function somewhere in your code. You'v just defined it.

Answer (score 0):

The image is `hidden` and the paragraph after it contains black text on a black background.

(The `imageappear` function, which you never call, mentions the `visible` property of the image which (a) has no effect since mentioning properties doesn't do anything and (b) doesn't exist. Assign `false` to the `hidden` property to turn off being hidden).